# Сгенерировать комбинации

Tags: php

Для выбора на сайте есть три чекбокса, в котором есть три варианта. Пользователь может выбрать 1 или 2 или 3 варианта. Обозначим варианты выбора в первом чекбоксе  как a,b,c, во втором - d,e,f, в третьем - x,y,z

Если пользователь выберет один вариант в каждом чекбоксе, то будет одна простая комбинация a-d-x, а если пользователь выберет два варианта в первой, то получим две комбинации a-d-x и b-d-x, а если пользователь выберет два варианта в первом и втором чекбоксе, то получим четыре комбинации a-d-x, b-d-x, a-e-x, b-e-x

Собственно вопрос: как сгенерировать комбинации в зависимости от выбора пользователя? Чекбоксов может быть даже 10 или 25

Comment: Так рекурсией. На каждом витке обрабатываем n-й чекбокс и присоединяем каждое значение к текущей подстроке. Окончание рекурсии - все чекбоксы обработаны, вывести вариант.

Comment: @Akina сможете ли подсказать как именно (кодом), а то я не программистка, а так балуюсь. Буду благодарна!

Comment: НУ так "балуйтесь". Идея высказана, реализуйте. Будут конкретные вопросы, по реализации конкретного места - обращайтесь. Сейчас Ваша просьба больше похожа на "сделайте за меня"... а вот вряд ли.

Comment: рекурсия по длине генерируемой строки. внутри функции цикл по вариантам для текущего индекса. когда глубина рекурсии достигает длины, то вывод строки.